# How do I access a datum's parent array from within a value function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to access a datum's parent array from within a value functions. Is there a way to do that without using a variable scoped to a higher level?

In other words,

```
var data = ["a", "b", "c"],
    svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {

        // how do I access `d's` parent array from here
        // without using the closure variable `data`?

    });
```

EDIT:

I'm avoiding the closure because my real world situation is more complex and creating this type of closure is awkward in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this (though I think the closure is the easiest option).

One way is to call `.data()` on the current selection:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data);

rect.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        console.log(rect.data());
    });
```

You need a variable to reference in this case. Another way to do this is to run it through `.call`, which gives you the current selection as an argument:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .call(function(selection) {
        // get the data into your scope
        var dataArray = selection.data();
        // do more stuff with the selection
        selection
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Nice, I think this is what I'm looking for! Side note, in your opinion do you think extending d3 to pass args `d`, `i`, **and** `data` to value functions is a bad idea? I've hit a few cases where having the full data set is handy. I might send a patch to the core for that behavior, but if I'm doing something odd I won't waste my time exploring it. Just trying to get a feel.

Comment: Hmm. Don't know how the d3 maintainers will feel about it - it might be useful, but there are some reasonably easy ways to access this, and the core API is kept pretty tight because of how many folks use it. In general, I'd rather change my code (e.g. add helpers) than fork a library if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same selection inside the element's attribute method and map each element in the selection to retrive the `__data__` attribute:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        // Select the parent, retrive the 'rect' items and get the __data__ of
        // each one
        var parent = d3.select(d3.select(this).node().parentNode),
        items = parent.selectAll('rect')[0],
        parentData = items.map(function(r) { return r.__data__; });
        console.log(parentData);
        return i * 20;
    });
```

I would rather use the svg variable, but it's possible to do what you want. You can find out more about the attribute `__data__` in the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data).

Comment: Thanks Pablo, this works, but feels fugly. Works > Broken though, so cool!

Comment: Yes, I would not recommend this method, but its a solution.